# Separate List<String> in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, stream

I need help on separating List. I am really new to this

I have a code that results to this

```
List<String> inputLetters = singletonList(Arrays.asList(setOfLetters(), "f").toString());
```

[[a, b, c, d, e], f]

setOfLetters() is from a query

My question is how can I make my result like this?

[a, b, c, d, e, f]

Is it by using for loop? Or anything you can suggest. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific problem I wouldn't try to loop through the array and solve it on this way.

My idea would be to just add the `"f"` to the `setOfLetters()` array. On this way you could avoid unnecessary code and solve the problem by using the static value.

Example:

```
// Assuming that setOfLetters() is a Set<String> we convert it to an ArrayList<>()
List<String> lettersSet = ArrayList<>(setOfLetters());
lettersSet.add("f");
```

On this way the List `lettersSet` would be `["a","b","c","d","e","f"]`.

Also if you want to change it to a SingletonList you can just use the whole `lettersSet` List.

Comment: According to the name, I would guess `setOfLetters()` returns a `Set<String>`.

Comment: @maloomeister If this is true it can simply be converted like this: ```List<Integer> lettersSet = new ArrayList<>(setOfLetters());```

Comment: Yes, I know, but OP might not know. I would use this assumption in your answer. But it was just a hint.

Comment: @maloomeister I edited my answer according to your comment. Thank you :)

Comment: The setOfLetters() returns a List. I tried adding a string "f" and make them ArrayofList but it says Arrays can't be cast as String.

Comment: the first answer you wrote is working now! thanks a lot!

Comment: @driedbananas Happy to hear :)